# Syntax error while calling sql query in JS

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, string, where-clause

I am trying to call this query from JS but I got syntax error. Here I am checking if value is equal to `""` or no but when I write this query inside `" "` in Js I got an error. How can I write this in Js differently.

```
"select * from Slot where Slot.TeacherID="T2" and (Slot.ReservedStudent IS NULL OR Slot.ReservedStudent ="")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner double quotes are clashing with the outer quotes. That's a syntax error in Javascript to begin with, before the database is hit.

You would better use single quotes within the SQL text - that's the standard character for literal strings anyway, while double quotes stand for identifiers such as column or table names (although some databases, such as MySQL, support double quotes for strings):

```
sql = "select * from Slot where Slot.TeacherID='T2' and (Slot.ReservedStudent IS NULL OR Slot.ReservedStudent = '')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it something like below ,use single quotes for values

```
"select * from Slot where Slot.TeacherID='T2' and (Slot.ReservedStudent IS NULL OR Slot.ReservedStudent ='')"
```